# Проекция объекта в матрицу камеры

Tags: python, математика, matlab

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня возник следующий вопрос. Есть множество координат объектов в пространстве в системе координат Земли, а еще есть камера, расположенная в конкретной точке и имеющая определенную ориентацию (повороты осей системы координат камеры). У этой камеры есть свои параметры: фокусное расстояние f, координаты оптического центра Oc=(cx,cy) и разрешение (ширина w и
высота h). Как при всем этом можно найти проекцию объектов на матрицу камеры? Если, например, объекты в совокупности образуют эллипс, то при определенной ориентации камеры должно статься так, что в объектив попадет только часть дуги. Я пыталась реализовать подобную вещь следующим образом (источник: https://waksoft.susu.ru/2020/02/23/geometriya-formirovaniya-izobrazhenij/): сначала перехожу в систему координат камеры и, соответственно, нахожу координаты объектов в ней. Потом умножаю матрицу проектирования K (ее вид можно найти по ссылке выше) на вектор координат конкретного объекта в новой системе координат (так делаю для каждого объекта). После пытаюсь сделать отбор точек, попавших в объектив. Но мне кажется, что я делаю что-то не так, потому что как бы я не меняла параметры поворота камеры, организовать ситуацию, где видно только часть объектов, не могу. Делаю я все это в матлабе. Код так же прилагаю.

```
%% Переход в систему координат камеры:

function [Pnew] = CameraCoords( xc,yc,zc,psi,theta,gamma,P )
r = quaternion(0,xc,yc,zc); % radius-vector of camera

L = quaternion(cos(psi/2)*cos(theta/2)*cos(gamma/2)-sin(psi/2)*sin(theta/2)*sin(gamma/2),...
               cos(psi/2)*cos(theta/2)*sin(gamma/2)+sin(psi/2)*sin(theta/2)*cos(gamma/2),...
               cos(psi/2)*sin(theta/2)*sin(gamma/2)+sin(psi/2)*cos(theta/2)*cos(gamma/2),...
               cos(psi/2)*sin(theta/2)*cos(gamma/2)-sin(psi/2)*cos(theta/2)*sin(gamma/2));
p = quaternion(0,P(1),P(2),P(3));              
L=L/norm(L);
Pnew = L*p*conj(L)+r;

Pnew = [Pnew.x Pnew.y Pnew.z];
end

%% Поиск проекции на матрицу камеры:   

function [u,v] = point2camProjection(point,f,Oc)
      
K = [f,0,Oc(1);0,f,Oc(2);0,0,1];
      
UVW = K*point;
u=UVW(1)/UVW(3);
v=UVW(2)/UVW(3); 
end

%% Само выполнение:

%%
Pnew=cell(length(Px),1);
for k=1:length(Px)
  Pnew{k}=CameraCoords( xc,yc,zc,50,150,14,[Px(k) Py(k) Pz(k)] ); % Px, Py, Pz - все координаты объектов по измерениям
end

%%
%w=2042; h=1856;
w=500; h=200;
UV=[];
for k=1:length(Pnew)
  [u,v] = point2camProjection(Pnew{k}',4.5,[round(w/2-1) round(h/2-1)]);
  if (u<=w)|(v<=h)
    UV=[UV;[u,v]];
  end
end
figure; grid on; hold on;
plot(UV(:,1),UV(:,2),'.')
```

Помимо этого, нужно после реализовать подобную процедуру, но уже при условии, что камера - рыбий глаз. Насколько я поняла, из-за этого меняется матрица проектирования, но я не понимаю, как. Заранее спасибо за помощь тех, кто откликнется)

Comment: Чисто из общих соображений - ваша задача не имеет решения, так как большинство объектов на матрице будут нерезкими. У почти всех предметных образ будет размыт. Что считать за координаты проекции в этом случае? Если у камеры есть фокусное расстояние, то нужно ещё указать расстояние от плоскости матрицы до фокальной плоскости.

Comment: Можете подробнее описать, почему появляется размытие?

Comment: По правилам геометрической оптики, расстояния от линзы до предмета и изображения связаны как `1/a + 1/b = 1/f`. Если расстояние от линзы до матрицы равно `b`, то резкими будут лишь предметы, находящиеся на расстоянии `1/a`. Попробуйте на своём телефоне навестись на какой-нибудь близкий предмет и посмотрите, как размоется фон.

Comment: Ну смотрите, считайте, что объекты - это точки на Земле, а камера находится на расстоянии 500-1000 км от ее поверхности. Я не думаю, что тут можно считать, что расстояние между объектом и камерой близкое.

Comment: Тут еще такой момент, что при каких-то углах в случае, когда объекты образуют эллипс, этот эллипс вырождается в гиперболу, а это, как мне кажется, не есть хорошо, хотя я пробовала и кватернионы для перехода в систему координат камеры, и просто матрицу перехода, но и там, и там возникает такая штука. Я, кстати, еще изменила условие "if (u<=w)|(v<=h)" на "if (u<=w)&(v<=h)&(u>=0)&(v>=0)", так что, вроде как, теперь можно получить часть дуги, но дуги именно гиперболы, для эллипса найти углы, при которых будет только часть дуги, не выходит.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что проблема с гиперболой возникает в функции point2camProjection.

Comment: Pnew{k}=CameraCoords( xc,yc,zc,50,150,14,[Px(k) Py(k) Pz(k)] ); % Px, Py, Pz - все координаты объектов по измерениям? Все.